# Trigger on GroupMember object

Tags: apex, trigger, public-group

I am trying to write a trigger to update user records as soon as they are added to a Group. So I decided to write a trigger on GroupMember but it says "SObject type does not allow triggers: GroupMember" is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't allow to write a trigger on `GroupMember` object. You should write a batch class to see the changes in `GroupMember` record.

There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l13GAAQ) around this, you can vote for on that idea.

Answer (score 3):

GroupMember Object is not triggerable..

Verified from workbench: /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/GroupMember

[image]

Comment: I am able to query members on GroupMember object and not on CollaborationGroupMember object.

Comment: @Ishan ..sorry I understood you are talking about chatter group....updated my reply..